# Some SCM Ambiguities

Tags: svn, version-control, maven

In reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control#Common_vocabulary) article on revision control, I found some terms that seem ambiguously-defined, and was wondering how they are actually used/applied in the real world. Specifically:

- "Mainline" vs "Baseline"
- "Branch" vs "Stream"
- "Checkout" vs "Update"
- "Vendor" folder vs artifact repo (like Maven or Ivy)

I am a contextual learner, so any concrete examples you could give would help the lightbulbs turn on a lot better.

With regards to the last one, what I mean is this:

At least in `svn` it is fairly standard to have a VC project structure of:

```
svnrepo/
    someProject/
        trunk/
        branches/
        tags/
        vendor/
```

Where `vendor/` is a place to put external/3rd party dependencies that your configurations rely on. Alternatively, I've seen developers use tools like Maven or Apache Ivy to pull/publish artifacts (JARs and such) to/from a repository, such as an SFTP server. **So when do you put 3rd party dependencies in your SCM under `vendor/`, and when do you put these dependencies in your Maven/Ivy repo?**

Thanks in advance for clarification on any of these items!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Mainline" vs "Baseline":
  The first term is a special kind of branch, which record the evolution of code, usually the one as seen in production. See [this chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/practicalperforce/chapter/ch07.pdf).
  The second term is about a label (set on all the file of a component, ie a coherent set of files)
- "Branch" vs "Stream":
  Branches have no hierarchies (you have a list of branches, and you merge from any branch to any branch). Streams have a hierarchy, which among other things allows for the definition of a [merge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212/how-do-you-maintain-development-code-and-production-code#216228).
- "Checkout" vs "Update"
  Checkout queries a specific version of the files and copy it on the disk.
  Update will make sure all the elements on the disk are up-to-date for the current selection rules.

---

- "Vendor" folder vs "artifact repo" (like Maven or Ivy)
  An artifact repo doesn't offer versioning features like merging, diff, branches.
  A Vendor is a dedicated branch in  a VCS (and should be avoided in my opinion: [binaries are not welcomed in a VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968745/many-binary-files-synchronization/4968834#4968834), unless for [certain reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709372/alternative-to-binaries-in-subversion/710090#710090))

> So when do you put 3rd party dependencies in your SCM under vendor/, and when do you put these dependencies in your Maven/Ivy repo?

You should try to keep vendor libs outside of the VCS, only versionning the `pom.xml` (for instance) which records the configuration (ie list of labels) you need for the third-parties libraries.